# angular link selection doesn't work on IOS safari

Tags: ios, angularjs, safari

I'm doing a responsive app using meteor and angular, and i have a share link functionality. On desktop it is an input field on read only and the user can copy the link. On mobile I want to do display an link with  tag. But on iOS safari doesn't react correctly when I long touch the link. Usually there is a menu of option that are displayed, but here just nothing happen.

my simple code : `<a  href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a>`

Thanks in advance to anybody that has an idea about this issue.

Update: I just tried wiht `<a  ng-href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a>` on Firefox android and it work perfectly. The issue is really an iOs case

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-href={{url}}` instead.

My guess is that iOS reads first the `{{url}}` as it is, and when angular updates it to whatever value is stored in the url variable, it does not pick up the new value. 
And because the string {{url}} is not valid url, it does not know how to work with that, so it does nothing.

(I am not iOS developer, but still, you should use `ng-href` for this)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

I tried : `       <div> <a class="linkshare" ng-href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a></div>
`
But same result. The safari iOS browser doesn't want to recognize it as a link.

Answer (score 0):

For long touch/press especially for mobile: Check this angular directive [link](https://gist.github.com/BobNisco/9885852)